# C++: Expected Constructor, Destructor or Type Conversion

Tags: c++, templates

Trying to learn C++. Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on this error (pun intended).

The class is a LinkedList (reproduced in its entirety below). The error occurs on this line:

```
LinkedList<T>::ListNode LinkedList::find(int pos) const {
```

and says:

> expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before
>   'LinkedList'

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
#ifndef LINKEDLIST_HPP
#define LINKEDLIST_HPP


#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class LinkedList {

    private:
        // a ListNode consists of the item and a pointer to the next ListNode
        struct ListNode {
            T data;
            ListNode *next;
        };
        int size; //Size of the list
        ListNode *head; //the beginning of the list

    public:
        LinkedList(); // default oonstructor
        ~LinkedList(); // destructor
        virtual bool isEmpty ();
        virtual int  getLength ();
        virtual void insert (int pos, T item);
        virtual T    remove (int pos);
        virtual T    retrieve (int pos);

        //helper methods
        LinkedList(LinkedList &copyList); //copy constructor
        ListNode *find (int pos) const; // internal find function
};

//default constructor
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList() {
    size = 0;
    head = NULL;
}

//destructor
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList() {
    //loop through each node, and delete it
    ListNode* current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        ListNode* next = current->next;
        delete current;
        current = next;
    }
    head = NULL; // set head node to back to null
}

//copy constructor
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(LinkedList& copyList) {
    size = copyList.size;

    // if copyList is empty
    if (copyList.head == NULL)
        head = NULL;

    else {
        //create a new head
        head = new ListNode;
        head->data = copyList.head->data;

        //create a new list
        ListNode *newPtr = head; // start at the head
        // iterate through rest of list to be copied
        for (ListNode *copyPtr = copyList.head->next; copyPtr != NULL; copyPtr = copyPtr->next) {
            newPtr->next = new ListNode;
            newPtr->data = copyPtr->data;
        }
        //make last ListNode's next point to NULL
        newPtr->next = NULL;
    }
}

template <class T>
bool LinkedList<T>::isEmpty() {
    if (size == 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}

template <class T>
int LinkedList<T>::getLength() {
    return size;
}

// used in other methods to find a given index
template <class T>
LinkedList<T>::ListNode LinkedList::find(int pos) const {

    // check that pos is in bound of LinkedList
    if ((pos < 1) || pos > getLength()) {
        cout << "Find position of out bounds" << endl;
        return NULL;
    } else { //search through ListNodes
        ListNode *temp = head; // start at the head
        for (int i = 1; i < pos; ++i)
            temp = temp->next;
        return temp;
    }
}


template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::retrieve(int pos) {
    T tempData; // to hold retrieved data
    try {
        if ((pos < 1) || (pos > getLength())) {
            cout << "Retrieve request outside LinkedList's bounds" << endl;
            return NULL;
        }
        else { //traverse list
            ListNode *temp = find(pos);
            tempData = temp->data;
            return tempData;
        }
    } catch (int e) {
        cout << "Could not retrieve position " << pos << endl;
    }
}

template <class T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(int pos, T item) {

    //check bounds
    if ((pos < 1) || (pos > getLength() +1))
        cout << "Must insert at a position between 1 and getLength() + 1" << endl;

    else {
        try {
            //create new ListNode
            ListNode *temp = new ListNode;
            temp->data = item;

            //if the new item is at the first position
            if (pos == 1) {
                temp->next = head;
                head = temp;
            }
            else {
                ListNode *prev = find(pos - 1);
                temp->next = prev->next;
                prev->next = temp;
            }
            //increment size
            ++size;

        } catch (int e) {
            cout << "Error inserting " << item << " at position " << pos << endl;
        }
    }
}

template <class T>
T LinkedList<T>::remove(int pos) {

    //check bounds
    if ((pos < 1) || (pos > getLength()))
        cout << "Must remove a position between 1 and getLength()" << endl;

    else {
        try {

            ListNode *temp; //to hold shifted node

            //if node to be deleted is first node
            if (pos == 1) {
                temp = head;
                head = head->next;
            }
            //for anything but the head
            //write over the node before the pos'th index
            else {
                ListNode *prev = find(pos - 1);
                temp = prev->next;
                prev->next = temp->next;
            }

            //destroy temp, to free up memory
            temp->next = NULL;
            delete temp;

            //decrement size
            --size;

        } catch (int e) {
            cout << "Error removing item from position " << pos << endl;
        }
    }


}

#endif  /* LINKEDLIST_HPP */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListNode` is a dependant type, so it needs to be qualified with `typename`.  Also, your `find` function was declared to return a pointer-to-`ListNode`, but the definition returns a `ListNode` by value.  This seems like a simple typo:

```
template <class T>
typename LinkedList<T>::ListNode* LinkedList<T>::find(int pos) const {
```

Comment: You have a few other issues as well.  Your destructor should be virtual, you need to make getLength const so that it can be used within your find function, and you shouldn't "use namespace" inside of a header.

Answer (score 1):

Qualify the dependant type with `typename` and add `<T>` (I'm not sure if this is necessary, might as well do it though):

```
typename LinkedList<T>::ListNode* LinkedList<T>::find(int pos) const {
```

See: [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords)

Also, your definition doesn't match. In-class it returns a pointer, but outside it returns a value.

Answer (score 0):

Should be

```
LinkedList<T>::ListNode LinkedList<T>::find(int pos) const {
```

Comment: Isn't `ListNode` dependent on a template type?

Comment: @K-ballo: isn't that covered by `LinkedList<T>::ListNode`